# For in Loop in Apple Swift

Tags: dictionary, for-loop

[image]

Why does it say `8 times` instead of `17 times`(all numbers) when evaluating the largest number?

Comment: Please [Edit] this to remove the image, and enter the code directly into the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays the number of time the line of statement is executed. In your case the line would be executed every time the `if` condition evaluates to `true`.

The condition within `if` would be reached for numbers which are greater than the existing number starting from index 0. Which in your case is only 8 times.

Comparisons between your `number` within the loop and the current `largest` would be as follows:

```
  number   largest

1. 2 > 0
2. 3 > 2
3. 5 > 3
4. 7 > 5
5. 11 > 7
6. 13 > 11
7. 16 > 13
8. 25 > 16
```

Comment: Oh! I skipped the condition "largest = number". Thanks for answering .